# JS in blazor component

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying create an alert message in within a Blazor component. I have no idea how to do this. I am running ASP.NET Core 3.1 Blazor server-side. Here's what  I've tried

Component function:

```
private async Task ShowAlert()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("ShowMsg");
    }
```

Javascript Interop:

```
function ShowMsg() {
    success = "Success!";
    return success; 
}
```

File `host.cshtml`:

```
 <script src="~/BlazorInterop.js"></script>
```

Comment: The docs might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@page "/"

<button @onclick="MessageBox">Show Message</button>

@code
{
    [Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
    protected async Task MessageBox()
    {
       await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("exampleJsFunctions.ShowMsg", 
                                                    "Hello Blazor");
     }
}
```

Put the following script tag beneath `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` in the `_Host.cshtml` file, like this:

```html
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script>
    window.exampleJsFunctions =
    {
        ShowMsg: function (message) {
            window.alert(message);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Lot of magic strings. Is there a better way today?